# Sticky Navigation when scrolling the page won't stick

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky

So it was working well when I just copied and pasted the code from an example within script tags in the HTML file. When I started scrolling down, the navbar eventually sticked to the top.

But I want to have my JS-code external. So I made an external file, added eventlisteners and so on. To test whether the extra functions work, I added some console.logs to it. The console shows me that actually everything is working.
Except for the fact, that the navbar is not sticky anymore.

I have already asked google and read through quite a lot other questions people have asked about the sticky navbar. Just didn't help.

Hope anyone knows a solution- what's wrong, why doesn't it work and what can I do to fix it?

```js
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function stickyNavbar() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
  console.log(navbar.classList);
}

function init() {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', stickyNavbar());
  console.log("init-function is successfully connected with document.addEventListener ")
}

document.addEventListener('load', init(), false);
document.addEventListener('load', console.log("page has loaded successfully "), false);
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
}

header {
  transform: none;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>

  <section class="container top-container">
    <h1>Innere Kinder</h1>
  </section>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: black">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

</header>

<body class="content">

  <section class="container">
    "Some example text that would have to be extended to actually show the sticky navbar feature"
  </section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: do you have any errors in your console?  I don't think you can do console logs over multiple lines

Comment: No errors... And I have deleted the console.logs just to try it. Still no luck.

Comment: Your html should only have one body tag and all html should be within it - if your header is outside the body tag then that is invalid html

Comment: Yes, right! Oh. I fixed that. But still the navbar won't stick.

Comment: I am sorry @MrLister I don't quite get what you are saying. That would mean the <nav> has to be outside of the <header>?

Comment: I fixed that, too. Still no success...

Comment: When I already AM scrolled down and reload the page, the navbar sticks to the top. If I reaload the page when I am all scrolled up the header, the navbar does not stick. Just in case this helps...

Comment: You can do it in css with `position: sticky`